# eclipse moxy @XmlPath combining predicates

Tags: java, xpath, moxy

I am trying to use moxy @XmlPath to parse values with combination of predicates, but it is not being parsed instead a null is assigned. I have tried both syntax for combining predicates.

```
 @XmlPath("Tag[@attr1='A'][@attr2='X']/text()")
    @XmlPath("Tag[@attr1='A' and @attr2='X']/text()")
    
    <Element>
    <Tag attr1="A" attr2="X">1</Tag>
    <Tag attr1="A" attr2="Y">2</Tag>
    <Tag attr1="B" attr2="X">3</Tag>
    <Tag attr1="C" attr2="Y">4</Tag>
    </Element>

    @XmlRootElement(name="Element") 
    ClassA{
    @XmlPath("Tag[@attr1='A'][@attr2='X']/text()")
    String ax;
    @XmlPath("Tag[@attr1='A'][@attr2='Y']/text()")
    String ay;
    @XmlPath("Tag[@attr1='B'][@attr2='X']/text()")
    String bx;
    @XmlPath("Tag[@attr1='B'][@attr2='Y']/text()")
    String by;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@` before the second attribute `attr2`.
Also looks like you are missing `//` at the beginning of the expressions.
These XPaths are returning the appropriate nodes texts:

```xml
"//Tag[@attr1='A'][@attr2='X']/text()"
"//Tag[@attr1='A'][@attr2='Y']/text()"
"//Tag[@attr1='B'][@attr2='X']/text()"
"//Tag[@attr1='C'][@attr2='Y']/text()"
```

Comment: I have and @XmlRootElement(name="Element") on the class ,, // is not supported by moxy and @ missed by mistake on the SO Question, let me edit

Comment: If so looks like it is `moxy` related issue while I'm not familiar with it, I'm sorry...